# defining perl indentation for emacs in source code file?

Tags: perl, emacs, indentation

Is it possible to put a comment at the top of a source Perl file to have Emacs abide by a 4-space indentation rule in that same file, regardless of the default indentation rule defined in `.emacs`?

I am finding myself editing Perl files with different indentations, some 2-spaced, some 4-spaced, and I would like Emacs to automatically follow the indentation rule described in the file itself, other than having to change the configuration every time.

All this is using `cperl-mode` for Perl editing (http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CPerlMode).

I tried adding the comments below at the end of this example perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my @a = (1,2,3,4,5,6);
for my $e (@a) {
  print "$e\n";
}

# Local variables:
# perl-indent-level: 4
# End:
```

But it still uses indent level 2. Maybe the reason is because it's not overriding the `.emacs` settings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should get it working by putting this at the *end* of the file:

```
# Local variables:
# perl-indent-level: 4
# End:
```

Comment: I tried adding the comments below at the end of an example perl script (see edited question), but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Maybe the reason is because it's not overriding the `.emacs` settings?

Comment: Change to `cperl-indent-level` -- you are setting it for the old, unrelated `perl-mode`.

Answer (score 1):

How about adding `(setq cperl-indent-level 4)` to your `.emacs` file? Found at [this page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IndentingPerl).